# AWS opswprks Chef and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Presently I'm working with AWS Opsworks to deploy mongodb cluster. I'm using https://github.com/netinlet/chef-mongodb_replicaset  repository to deploy. Unfortunately when i'm trying to connect  more  then 7 instances, I have error:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: replSet bad config maximum number of voting members is 7",
    "code" : 13612,
    "ok" : 0  "
```

I was  thinking, that  it's an SSL certificate problem, but I've arrange pem keys to each instance separately. Still have the same error.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Also configuration of  priority didn't  help...

Comment: Sounds OT for SO, but let's get the requirements straight: are you expecting the chef recipe to automatically create non-voting members? Why would you have more than 7 members in a replica set anyway?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? Pre 3.0, the maximum number of members of a replica set was 12.In 3.0, it's 50. In both 3.0 and previous versions, the maximum number of voting members in a replica set is 7. Your configuration won't work because it has too many voting members. You need to reduce the size of the replica set or make some members non-voting.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday, i've  read the  Mongodb documentation, and  figured my question about replSet members.  I've  used   2.4.3, but  now  i'm deploying  on 3.0.1.